# Azure pipelines bind to localhost for tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to run integration tests in Azure Pipelines by spinning up a web server and hitting it with HTTP requests in a different process.

The error I received is

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:49159: address already in use.)
```

The code that seems to generate the error is

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:49159")
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.Run(handler);
                })
                .Build();

                builder.Start();
```

I have tried a bunch of different ports so assume that you just cannot bind to localhost on Azure Pipelines.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do with Azure Pipelines?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, you want to use [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to spin up your service from within a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Maybe you're starting the web host more than once and not detroying it (i.e. for each test fixture, etc.)?

In general, these are some of possible ways to run integration tests in the pipeline:

- If your integration tests are written in .Net, then consider using [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) to run server & tests in a single process.
- If you use different tools for integration tests,
  node's [start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test) module does a great job of starting your server, waiting for it to be ready and then executing tests (you can use it for .Net projects as well). Here's [a sample pipeline for .Net project](https://dev.azure.com/heavymetaldev/heavymetaldev/_build/results?buildId=138&view=logs&j=12f1170f-54f2-53f3-20dd-22fc7dff55f9&t=7dae026f-9e99-5d65-075e-3f7579577f94).

Comment: arghhh yes thank you it was the absolute classic of..Yes, it's definitely possible. Maybe you're starting the web host more than once and not detroying it (i.e. for each test fixture, etc.)? I guess the agents are not as quick as the old laptop!

Comment: Hey @TomPallister did u get this to work? I’m trying to use npx http-server and I seem to have problems binding to a port in hosted machines